# dotnet Web API - MSAL ( Microsoft.Identity.Web ) register multiple authentication providers

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am developing a Web API and using the Microsoft.Identity.Web libraries for securing the APIs.

I have a scenario where different APIs / Controllers need to accept tokens issued by different Azure AD App Registrations

At the moment, I have something like this:

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("Api1"));

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Build();
});

...

//Controller1
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{...}
```

In the example Above, I use `Api1` Configuration section to provide a `ClientID`/`Tenant`/`Audience` values for my Azure AD App registration.

I would like to be able to add another Authorization "rule" (?) in a way that I can configure Controller2 to accept tokens from a second App Registration:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("Api1"));
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("Api2")); //this probably won't work as it will clobber the services instance?

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Build();
});

...

//Controller1
[Authorize] --- With Api1 settings?
[ApiController]
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{...}


//Controller2
[Authorize] --- With Api2 settings?
[ApiController]
public class Controller2 : ControllerBase
{...}
```

The requirements of why I need to use 2 different app registrations are outside of my scope and cannot change.

Currently, I solved this by creating 2 Web API projects / apps but it's come to a point where I really like to consolidate these if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you can indeed register multiple Authentication profiles and you use the `jwtBearerScheme` as the differentiator when you want to validate against one or another.

For Authentication, you can define different authentication requirements for each of the schemes as follows:

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(
    Configuration.GetSection("Api1"),
    jwtBearerScheme: "Api1Scheme"
);
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(
    Configuration.GetSection("Api2"),
    jwtBearerScheme: "Api2Scheme"
); 

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Api2Policy", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Api2Scheme")
        .RequireRole("SomeRole")
        .Build());
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Api1Scheme")
        .Build();
});

...

//Controller1
[Authorize] //Because ApiScheme1 is registered as the Default Authorization, no disambiguation needed here
[ApiController]
public class Controller1 : ControllerBase
{...}


//Controller2
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api2Scheme", Policy = "Api2Policy")] 
[ApiController]
public class Controller2 : ControllerBase
{...}
```